Put Invoice - Error 10 - Invoice Type must be specified
I am using Postman to Put a new invoice into Xero and am receiving an Error Number 10. The body of my command is:
{
    "parameters": {
        "xero-tenant-id": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "Accept": "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "body": {
            "Type": "ACCREC",
            "Reference": "Pick Up",
            "Contact": {
                "ContactID": "5fc528e0-3a47-4c02-bede-f73fd6ec2709"
            },
            "LineItems": [
                {
                    "Quantity": 504,
                    "ItemCode": "1422.7"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}


The response I receive is:
{
    "ErrorNumber": 10,
    "Type": "ValidationException",
    "Message": "A validation exception occurred",
    "Elements": [
        {
            "InvoiceID": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
            "Payments": [],
            "CreditNotes": [],
            "Prepayments": [],
            "Overpayments": [],
            "IsDiscounted": false,
            "InvoiceAddresses": [],
            "HasErrors": true,
            "InvoicePaymentServices": [],
            "Status": "DRAFT",
            "LineItems": [],
            "ValidationErrors": [
                {
                    "Message": "Invoice Type must be specified"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}

I believe I use the correct Invoice Type. Does anyone have suggestions how to fix?

You can check your logs here
Once logged in, select your App and click on the "history" tab.  Here you will be able to filter the logs by method, status, date and endpoint.
Successful calls will have the response redacted, but this is particularly useful for looking at your unsuccessful calls and it will show you the JSON payload received by Xero.
If this all looks correct, please can you raise a case with Xero Support here with the time, date and timezone for the most recent error and the client id of your app
